# How to find which scales are available in SeqUtil of Biopython?

Tags: phylogenetics, python, phylogeny

I am trying to analyse the hydrophobicity of a sequence using BioPython's "SeqUtil".

```
analysed_seq = ProteinAnalysis("AKVLGSLEALEPVHYEEKNWCE")
analysed_seq.protein_scale(Scale, WindowSize, Edge)
```

**Known parameters**

- `WindowSize` refers to the total number of amino acids to be considered either side of the residue (an `int` variable).
- `Edge` refers to the weighting of the scale further from the centre of the window (0-1). `

**Unknown parameter**

- Scale`refers to which scale being used. I am interested in how to give the`Scale` variable a valid variable.

The [Biopython docs](http://biopython.org/wiki/ProtParam) simply point out that there are many `scales` to choose from and the [source code](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam-pysrc.html#ProteinAnalysis.protein_scale) doesn't seem to give any clues about scale options.

Where can I find a list of the `scale` are available and how to call them?

Comment: what do you mean? There is no scale argument to feed `protein_scale()` only `def protein_scale(self, param_dict, window, edge=1.0):` https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqUtils/ProtParam.py#L211. I think `param_dict` is `kd` https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqUtils/ProtParamData.py#L6

Comment: @Chris_Rands You've answered the question, thanks. I was looking for any predefined `param_dict` arguments and the GitHub source code spells them out clearly. It also looks like you can feed a scale straight in without having to edit `ProtParamsData` which satisfies me more.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code:

```
print(analysed_seq.protein_scale(analysed_seq.get_amino_acids_percent(), window=9, edge=0.4))
```

Comment: Welcome to the forum.  Can you add some context as to what this line is doing and why it answers the question?